# Determining ionic build platform in after prepare hook

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Let say that I have execute an `ionic run android` or `ionic build android` command. And i have an `after prepare` hook script. I would like to know whether i am building an android or other platform in the `after prepare` script so that i can perform the correct action in the script. How could it be done?

Something i would expect:

```
if (ionic.build.platform === 'android')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this using separate settings in config.xml for your hook scripts, then either have one hook script per platform, or maybe use parameters passed to your hook script to identify the platform.

For example, you might want to do something like:

```
<platform name="android">
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="scripts/android/after_prepare.sh" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="scripts/ios/after_prepare.sh" />
</platform>
```

Source: [Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html).